# How to map on array of objects and change styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have messages array and I am using `map()` now each message has 2 keys one is `author` and other is `message`. So when the last message is displayed I want to change the styles of that div tag how can I do that ? So while mapping on messages array if the array element is the last one then add div with changed styles (changed styles here mean like some shadow or background focus on that div tag) How can I do this ?

Code:

```
 <div id="messages" className="card-block">
                            {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {

                                if(message.author === this.props.match.params.user){
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBoxRight"><p className="msgTextRight">{message.message}</p></div>
                                    )
                                }else{
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBoxLeft"><p className="msgTextLeft">{message.message}</p></div>
                                    ) 
                                }  
                            })}
                        </div>
```

Screenshot of chat app:

[image]

So I want the latest message i.e the last message in chat box to have different styles maybe background focus or box shadow how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use css selector `:last-child`:

```css
.block .message {
  background-color: #ff0000
}

.block .message:last-child {
  background-color: #00ff00
}
```

```html
<div class="block"> 
  <div class="message">message </div>
  <div class="message">message </div>
  <div class="message">message </div>
  <div class="message">last message</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between `index` and `length` of an array as follows:

```
index = length - 1
```

So you can know which object in the array is last by:

```
if (index + 1 === length) {
  // Add custom styling here
}
```

Give that a try!